# Start mysql with nfs floder is failed.But deleted "ibdatafile*" succed again

Tags: mysql, innodb, nfs

I use vagrant to controller my vbox with centos7.Also,i installed all the needed plugin include bindfs and winnfs and so on ....I want to share the mysql datadir with nfs like this: D:/vagrant_db => /vagrant_db.But still have eror :

```
2016-07-01T08:27:21.046795Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The Auto-extending innodb_system data file './ibdata1' is of a different size 0 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .\
cnf file: initial 768 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
2016-07-01T08:27:21.046826Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2016-07-01T08:27:21.648185Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-07-01T08:27:21.648265Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-07-01T08:27:21.648282Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2016-07-01T08:27:21.648370Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-07-01T08:27:21.648451Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-07-01T08:27:21.648619Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-07-01T08:27:21.649646Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

ls -al /vagrant_db/mysql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    16384 Jul  7 11:04 ibdata1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql  1204224 Jul  7 11:04 ib_logfile0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Jul  7 09:22 ib_logfile1

emacs /etc/my.cnf
#datadir=/var/lib/mysql
datadir=/vagrant_db/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#socket=/vagrant_db/mysql.sock
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

I know there something wrong with the file "ibdata".So when i rm the file "ibdata*" and "ib_logfile*",the mysqld start normally!But once i stop the mysqld,and start again,it will error as before!

Would i rm the file every time before i start mysqld?

Please ,i need help.....It's tough!

Comment: Show us the ibdata clause in my.cnf.   Show us `ls -l ibdata*` when it fails.

Comment: @RickJames I have already improved the problem.

Comment: Strange -- how can the two logfiles be different size??

Comment: @RickJames Yes.But i have no idea about it.even though i have deleted these files,when mysqld started,the two logfiles still have diferent size.